# Getting error while using fortify function in R (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use the function fortify in R to plot the map. But I am always getting an error while processing the data. I read the shape file using the following code:

```
shape <- readShapeSpatial("Lond_City/lond_city.shp")
```

The shapefile can be found on the following dropbox location:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d4w6saailydtu1r/5oIa56xV6S

Then I tried to use the following command :

```
shape1 <- fortify(shape,region="data")
```

In the above code, what should I put in Place of "data". This is the place which seems confusing. I can open the data or shapefile in R. However, when I run the fortify line I get the following error:

> Error in '[.data.frame'(attr, , region) : undefined columns selected

Can anybody tell me how to properly fortify a shape file with example ? The reason I want to use fortify is that I want to combine the shape file with the data points.

Thank you so much.

Jdbaba

Comment: It looks like you're using something from the Ordnance Survey? If you can make a link to the shapefile so that others can download it, or explain **exactly** where you got the data from, then I think we can probably help.

Comment: Slowlearner, thank you for your reply. I have added the link of the shapefile in the question. Please have a look. thanks.

Comment: Thank you for that. You will nearly always get a faster and better response on StackOverflow if you provide data as well as code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to give `fortify` a column that actually exists. If you type `str(lon.shape)` from my example code below, you will see that there is no `region` column:

```
> str(lon.shape)
Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  7 variables:
  .. ..$ ons_label: chr "00AA"
  .. ..$ name     : chr "City of London"
  .. ..$ label    : chr "02AA"
  .. ..$ X_max    : num 533843
  .. ..$ y_max    : num 182198
  .. ..$ X_min    : num 0
  .. ..$ y_min    : num 0
  ..@ polygons   :List of 1
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ Polygons :List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] 532464 181220
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ area   : num 3151465
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ hole   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ ringDir: int 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords : num [1:771, 1:2] 531027 531029 531036 531074 531107 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ plotOrder: int 1
  .. .. .. ..@ labpt    : num [1:2] 532464 181220
  .. .. .. ..@ ID       : chr "0"
  .. .. .. ..@ area     : num 3151465
  ..@ plotOrder  : int 1
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 530967 180404 533843 182198
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slots
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs"
```

Instead, try using `name`, like this:

```
lon.df <- fortify(lon.shape, region = "name")
```

Which produces this data frame:

```
> head(lon.df)
      long      lat order  hole piece            group             id
1 531026.9 181611.1     1 FALSE     1 City of London.1 City of London
2 531028.5 181611.2     2 FALSE     1 City of London.1 City of London
3 531036.1 181611.5     3 FALSE     1 City of London.1 City of London
4 531074.0 181610.3     4 FALSE     1 City of London.1 City of London
5 531107.0 181609.3     5 FALSE     1 City of London.1 City of London
6 531117.1 181608.9     6 FALSE     1 City of London.1 City of London
```

Here's one way to go about it, start to finish:

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)

shape.dir <- "c:/test/london" # use your directory name here

lon.shape <- readOGR(shape.dir, layer = "lond_city")
lon.df <- fortify(lon.shape, region = "name")

ggplot(lon.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(colour = "black", fill = "grey80", size = 1) +
    theme()
```

...resulting in the following:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: SlowLearner, Thank you so much for your wonderful solution. But it seems like I cannot run because I get the following error "isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE. Do you know how to fix this ? I tried to install "gpclibPermit" but it says this package is not available for version 2.15.2. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Jdbaba This is because SlowLearner is using ```readOGR``` rather than ```readShapeSpatial```. You can fix this by running gpclibPermit() but be careful as this is forbidden if you are using the software for a commercial purpose. You may prefer to avoid this issue by adopting the approach in my answer. Alternatively you can install the ```rgeos``` package which has no commercial restriction and should also fix the problem.

Comment: @Jdbaba `readOGR` preserves the proj4 information so I generally prefer it. I have edited my answer a little to include `gpclib` and the `gpclibPermit()` call.

Comment: @SlowLearner If you include ```library(rgeos)``` you do not need to run ```gpclibPermit()``` as well, since ```rgeos``` is an alternative to gpclib.

Comment: @orizon Ah, thanks for that, guess that's why in another piece of code I have there **is** an unexplained call to `rgeos`! I get confused as to which libraries supply what: `sp`, `map`, `maptools`, `gpclib`, `rgdal`, `rgeos` all get mixed up together in my head. Will edit.

Comment: Thanks guys for clearing things up. I have another task to do. I need to add the points and contour to the plot and clip the contour by the shapefile. Is that possible in R ? Thanks.

Comment: @Jdbaba On StackOverflow we like to do things "one question at a time" so please make this a separate question and include the data (or fake data that resembles the real data).

Comment: @Jdbaba Yes it is possible, search for answers on http://gis.stackexchange.com/ as well as StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You should put `label` in place of `data`.

```
require(maptools); require(ggplot2)
shape <- readShapeSpatial("Lond_City/lond_city.shp")
shape1 <- fortify(shape,region="label")
```

To find this out I inspected the data element of `shape`:

```
> shape@data
  ons_label           name label    X_max    y_max X_min y_min
0      00AA City of London  02AA 533842.7 182198.4     0     0
```

This shows `ons_label` or `name` would also have worked and may be more suitable for your purposes.

Note that your shape file is slightly unusual because there seems to be only one group.